# fluent nhibernate polymorphism. how to check for type of class

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have an Icon which has a Content (one to one) relationship.

```
public class Icon
{
   public virtual Content Content {get; set;}
}
```

By default, it is lazy loaded which is what I want.
However, at some point in the code, I need to check what kind of Content is, Content being polymorphic, something like

```
if(icon.Content is TextContent)
{
 ...
}
```

Icon is part of another association and it is automatically obtained by the NHibernate, I do not get it manually.

What is the recommended way of checking for the actual type in this situation?

I can have a specific property like ContentType which will be an enum in order to identify the actual content type, but I am looking to know if there's a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions but meanwhile I found an interesting solution, better I think.

Using the Visitor pattern, I can define an IconContent visitor and pass an Action to be executed to it.
For example, suppose there is a TextContent and an ImageContent, it will be something like this:

```
IconContentVisitor.Func(()=> {  Console.WriteLine("this is TextContent"; }, ()=> { Console.WriteLine("this is ImageContent"));
```

Idea came from here: http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/991

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that kind of check, you have to remove the proxy from the property.
There is a few ways to do it:

1. If you have access to the session call:

   ```
   session.PersistenceContext.Unproxy(icon.Content);
   ```
2. Implement a virtual method (in a base class if possible) that forces the removal of the proxy by returning the instance with the proper type.

   ```
   public virtual U As<U>() where U : YourType {
       return this as U;
   }
   ```
3. Disable the lazy initialization of the property.

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491749/inheritance-and-lazy-loading-in-nhibernate).

To add to csanchez's list, a fourth method is to add a `Self` property to the Content base class that returns the un-proxied type:

```
public virtual void Self
{
   get { return this; }
}
```

And a fifth method is to use 'lazy="no-proxy"` in the mapping [as described on Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/blog/4378/nhibernate-new-feature-no-proxy-associations).