# Inheritance and lazy loading in NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, inheritance, lazy-loading

Take the following classes:

```
public class Employee 
{ 
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}

public class ShopFloorEmployee : Employee { ... }

public class OfficeEmployee : Employee { ... }

public class Department 
{
    public Employee Manager { get; set; }
}
```

and here are the NHibernate mapping files:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                     namespace="Domain.Entities" 
                     assembly="Domain">
    <class name="Employee">
      <id name="Id" column="Id" type="long">
        <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <discriminator column="Type" type="string"/>
      <many-to-one name="Manager" class="Employee" column="ManagerId" lazy="proxy" />

      <subclass name="ShopFloorEmployee" discriminator-value="ShopFloorEmployee" extends="Employee"/>
      </subclass>

      <subclass name="OfficeEmployee" discriminator-value="OfficeEmployee" extends="Employee"/>
      </subclass>

    </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                     namespace="Domain.Entities" 
                     assembly="Domain">
    <class name="Department">
      <id name="Id" column="Id" type="long">
        <generator class="identity"/>
      </id>
      <discriminator column="Type" type="string"/>
      <many-to-one name="Manager" class="Employee" column="ManagerId" lazy="proxy" />
    </class>
  </hibernate-mapping>
```

These proxies seem to be causing me problems. For instance, if I load a Department, the Manager of that department (let's call him Bob, who is a ShopFloorEmployee) will be of type EmployeeProxy. Then, in the same session, if I specifically load a list of all ShopFloorEmployees, they will all be of type ShopFloorEmployee except Bob, who will be of type EmployeeProxy. I then can't cast Bob as a ShopFloorEmployee at all, because it has followed a different inheritance path.

The proxies are necassary to avoid recursively loading loads of Employees via their manager each time I load either a Department or Employee.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here, or is this a quirk of NHibernate? If it is a quirk then is there a work around? I have considered explicitly closing the session after loading the department but this seems just too hacky.

Comment: If people need it, when I get a moment, I will add the query code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common workaround for this issue is to add a `Self` property to access the non-proxied type:

```
public virtual Employee Self
{
   get { return this; }
}
```

Then you can check `Bob.Self is ShopFloorEmployee`.

Personally I use inheritance very sparingly and I would use a "role" property here instead of subclassing.

Comment: This was a good solution to fix a problem in an existing domain. If i was designing it from the start, I would use khelland's answer, but this helped me the most in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common [NHibernate pitfall](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2012/08/02/nhibernate-pitfalls-inheritance-and-proxies.aspx). Try changing the `Manager` reference to a [No proxy association](http://ayende.com/blog/4378/nhibernate-new-feature-no-proxy-associations).

Comment: I'm not sure why this dodn't work for me, it is likely I have done something wrong. I'm trying to fix a problem in a complex domain. If I had known this from the start I could have designed it in, and it would have been the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, see here: 
[fluent nhibernate polymorphism. how to check for type of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484939/fluent-nhibernate-polymorphism-how-to-check-for-type-of-class/13543390#13543390)

I chose to use a solution based on the Visitor pattern

You do not need to turn off lazy loading nor use funny properties to return the self object